# How to avoid continual repitition of characters in a text field?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to check a "textarea" field to make sure it doesn't contain characters repeated 3 or more times like listed below:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
ggggggggggggggg
ddddddddddddd
```

How can I do this using Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: how many letters do you consider a repitition?

Comment: "Aa a A" is a valid bavarian sentence :-)

Comment: let's say 3 because I believe no english word use any alphabet more than twice

Comment: @Bergi Now I'm curious. I'd like to know what that means.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: "Also an 'A'" :-)

Comment: @Bergi Ahh that makes sense, I guess.

Comment: @user1934643: What exactly do you mean by "make sure it doesn't contain"? Prevent a user from typing them? Display an "invalid" message? What should happen if they're pasted in, should they be removed?

Comment: Are you asking how to detect repetitions of 3 or more characters? (For example, flag 'Eeew' but not 'Aardvark'?

Comment: I have to detect and avoid this repition by showing an alert error when a user clicks on submit button on the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using regular expressions:

```
var hasDuplicate = (/^([a-zA-Z])\1+$/).test(str)
```

Comment: This is a good start, but it would match `"aa"`. You'd need `"\1{2,}"` or `'\1\1+"` to match 3 or more letters. Plus it won't find repetitions within a string, like `"thiiis"`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pinch, but if you want to do it manually, you could always:

1. Split the textarea into an array on white spaces (get an array of words)
2. run in a loop on all words
3. for each word, run in a loop on characters `0` to `length-2`, and check to see if the following 2 are not the same as the current.

Did I say I agree with pinch already? :)